# Spring JMS programmatic listener endpoints and transactions

Tags: spring-jms

When I register JMS listener endpoints programmatically, I do not have transactional support anymore.

I'm using TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy with a JDBC datasource and JMS, which gives nice global transactions like JTA does (1PC global tx). Using annotations it works just fine:

```java
@JmsListener(containerFactory = "jmsQueueListenerContainerFactory", destination = "queue/exampleQueue")
@Transactional
public void onQueueMessage(Message message, Session session) {...}
```

But with programmatic endpoint registration it does not work. The endpoint registration code:

```java
@Override
public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
    registrar.setContainerFactory(jmsListenerContainerFactory());
    SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
    endpoint.setId("Oelieboeliwieli");
    endpoint.setDestination("queue/exampleQueue");
    endpoint.setMessageListener(new Consumer());
    registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint);
}
```

And the listener is just:

```java
@Transactional
public void onMessage(Message message) { ... }
```

Everything else is the same in the two cases. My guess is that there is no proxy generated for the `onMessage()` method that handles the global transaction. With the annotated solution I see a proxy generated called from `invokeWithinTransaction()`.

Any idea how to do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the `Consumer` by hand so that object is not a managed bean at all. There is no reason (and no way really) for the application context to process that class and create a proxy for it.

Whatever is creating the message listener should take a managed bean instead. Given the code you've provided, it's hard to understand why you need to go with a programmatic registration though but that's an entirely different topic.

Comment: As to the reason why, I could have done it with Conditional stuff too I guess. But I also really wanted to understand this, because you put Transactional while doing JDBC and JMS and it seems to work yet you don't have a global tx. One really needs to test failure scenarios to see if it works or not. In non-JEE environment that is.